# Is it safe to distribute a Dropbox client secret with the application?

Tags: ruby, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api, app-secret

Is it safe to distribute a Dropbox client secret with the application?

For example, if I wanted to release an open source project, I would need to embed the client secret into the application (since Dropbox uses oauth 1.0).

How can this be done without the potential for abuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the secret as an environment variable, then when developers use your open source app they can replace it with their own Dropbox key.

Then, exclude the file with the environment variables from your source control.

You could additionally put in some handling that raises a specific exception if the environment variable isn't set, so they know what's missing and what they have to do.

I doubt you need everyone who uses your app using your secret key, and most developers won't want to anyway, in case you ever remove it.